# How can I adjust the appearance of the Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, stylesheet

Kindly help me How can i customize the text&charfield(length,breadth,font,colour) without using templates for the following code

```
 class Record(models.Model):
        Name   = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True,help_text="Employee Name")
        Empid  = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True,help_text="Employee ID")
        Salary = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
        Bonus  = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: Those things are not properties of model fields, they are UI properties.  The proper place to edit UI properties is in the UI container (ie. The TEMPLATE)

Answer (score 1):

In your admin.py:

```
class RecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # your stuff...

    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("my_styles.css",)
        }
```

[Documentation for `class Media`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions)

Now you should be able to override what you want in the `my_styles.css` file.

If you want a more general solution (not only for `Record` model but for many models), a good way to do it is to extend the `base_site.html` template to add your own CSS file to all admin pages.

```
{% block blockbots %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/admin_base.css" />
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

I put it in `blockbots` instead of `extrastyle` to be sure it will be at the end so it will override all other stylesheets.

[Documentation on overriding/extending admin templates.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to modify the visual elements of the Django admin from the model.  This would totally defeat the purpose of an MVC framework!  Separation of concerns dictates that these changes would be done in the template.

If you want to change the text size you'll have to modify the stylesheets for the admin.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to create Forms from your Models and to customize them, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) is the oficial doc.

Use [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) to customize with HTML attributes